# How do I read yaml dict value without using array?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a test1.yaml file like below

```
  accounts:
  - name: account1
    dockerRegistries: 
    - set1
    - set2
    - set3
  - name: account2
    dockerRegistries: 
    - set2
    - set4
    - set5
  - name: account3
    dockerRegistries:
     - set2
     - set5
     - set4
```

I need the dockerRegistries value for a particular name.

I have tried the below after reading the yaml file :

```
     accounts = []
     account_name = y['kubernetes']['accounts']
     for account in account_name:
        accounts.append(account['name'])
     if account['name'] == 'account1':
        print(y['kubernetes']['accounts'][0]['dockerRegistries'])
```

The above code gives value according to the array 0,1 and so on . But I want the value of dockerRegistries according to the if condition.

If I am giving

```
        if account['name'] == 'account1'
```

I want

```
        ["set2", "set4", "set5"]
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe it would be more understandable if you at least could use standard nomenclature: a YAML `mapping` is loaded in a Python dict, a YAML sequence in a Python `list`. It is also quite unclear how you get the value for the `dockerRegistries` key under `name: account2` when you check for `account1`. If you do `if account['name'] == 'account2'`, do you then want the value `["set2", "set5", "set4"]`?

Comment: @Anthon ohhh yes , when it is account2. I could do that. Can you help me how I can add another value to the dockerRegistries such as set6 ?

Comment: If you post a new question specifying what exactly you want to do (including the program you got, the input and the expected output) then I can help, but not here in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to move the `if` to the inside of the `for` loop. Something like this:

```
accounts = []
account_name = y['kubernetes']['accounts']
for account in account_name:
    accounts.append(account['name'])
    if account['name'] == 'account1':
        print(account['dockerRegistries'])
```

Depending on the number of accounts and what else you want to do with them, a dictionary might be a sensible solution:

```
accounts = {account['name']:account for account in y['kubernetes']['accounts']}
print(accounts['account1']['dockerRegistries'])
```